# How do I graph this in python?

Tags: python

$$
    y=\cases{-\sqrt{|x|}, \quad x\le0\\\sqrt{x}, \quad x>0}
$$

I've tried graphing this in python, but can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know how to do this by chance?

Comment: How have you tried to plot it? Are you stuck with the syntax, or how to mathematically express this?

Comment: Look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html

Answer (score 2):

You can reinterpret it as follows:

```
np.sign(x) * np.sqrt(np.abs(x))
```